# Why the integral $\int_0^3 \frac{1}{x^2-6x+5}dx$ doesn't exist?

Tags: improper-integrals

Why the integral $\int_0^3 \frac{1}{x^2-6x+5}dx$ doesn't exist?
$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \lim_{t\to 1^{-}} [\arctan(2-3/2) - \arctan(-3/2)] + \lim_{t\to 1^+}[\arctan(0/2) - \arctan(1-3/2)]
$$
I can find $\arctan(0)= \pi/2$

So why the answer in my book is doesn't exist?

Comment: For it to exist, the function $x\mapsto \dfrac 1{x^2-6x+5}\color{grey}{=\dfrac 1{(x-1)(x-5)}}$ needs to be integrable on $[0,3]$. Well is it?

Comment: Arctan(0) = ???

Comment: @Claude yes, arctan (0)=pi/2

Comment: @user32104 That's incorrect.

Comment: @Git Gud, yes so that's why I use limit of t

Comment: @Git do you mean arctan0=pi/2 is incorrect ?

Comment: @user32104 It isn't integrable around $1$ (and around $5$, but this doesn't matter). As for $\arctan(0)=\dfrac \pi 2$, if it were true, it would mean that $\tan (arctan(0))=\tan\left(\dfrac \pi 2\right)$, but $\dfrac \pi 2$ isn't in the domain of $\tan$.

Comment: Yes that's right but arctan(0)=0 right?so we find the answer as converge , because I didn't see any infinity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $a,b,\alpha$ be real numbers such that $a<b$.
>
> The integrals $\displaystyle \int \limits_a^{b^-} \frac{1}{(b-x)^\alpha}\mathrm dx , \int \limits_{a^+}^b \frac{1}{(x-a)^\alpha}\mathrm dx$ converge if, and only if, $\alpha <1$.

**Hint:** $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left((x^2-6x+5)=(x-1)(x-5)\right)$.

Comment: @Git thank you I already know that my problem is why after integrate this the answer in my book is infinite but I can find the answer so it's converge as you know arctan(0)=pi/2

Comment: As discussed in the comments in the question, the equality $\arctan(0)=\dfrac \pi 2$ is incorrect. Regarding your work, I need some help because I don't understand what you're doing. Why are you even messing with $\arctan$? Can it be that you miscalculated the antiderivatives?

Comment: @gud I will right what I did, x^2-6x*5=(x-3)^2-4=4[((x-3)/2)^2-1], then x-3/2=tan@, dx=2sec^2@ d@ so the integral will be 1/2(sec^2@/sec^2@)= 1/2 @=1/2 arctan(x-3/2), and now 1/2(lim{t->1-}[arctan(x-3/2) (from 0 to t)]+ lim {t->1+}[arctan(x-3/2) (from t to 3)) please help

Comment: @user32104 It seems to me you're using the identity $(\tan(\theta))^2-1=(\sec(\theta))^2$, which is false. Correct would be $(\tan(\theta))^2+1=(\sec(\theta))^2$

Comment: Omg, thank you finally I know what's wrong

Comment: @user32104 No problem.

Comment: @user32104: We would have been able to spot that mistake if you had included your work in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}$ is undefined at $x = 1$ so

$$\int_0^3\frac{1}{(x - 1)(x-5)}dx = \lim_{s\to 1^-}\int_0^s\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}dx + \lim_{t\to 1^+}\int_t^3\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}dx.$$

To evaluate the two integrals on the right, we need to find an antiderivative. We do this by first applying partial fraction. Doing so we obtain

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)} = \frac{-\frac{1}{4}}{x-1} +\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{x-5}.$$

Therefore $-\frac{1}{4}\ln|x-1| + \frac{1}{4}\ln|x-5| = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{x-5}{x-1}\right|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}$. Therefore

$$\int_0^s\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}dx = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{s-5}{s-1}\right| - \frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{0-5}{0-1}\right| = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{s-5}{s-1}\right| -\frac{1}{4}\ln 5.$$

As $\lim\limits_{s\to 1^-}\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{s-5}{s-1}\right|$ does not exist, $\lim\limits_{s\to 1^-}\int_0^s\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}dx$ does not exist, so $\int_0^3\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-5)}dx$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you !! Is it right to say x^2-6x*5=(x-3)^2-4=4[((x-3)/2)^2-1], then x-3/2=tan@??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've written, but I'm not sure if it will help you calculate the integral.

Comment: The fact you can establish the antiderivative and the fact that you can comute the integral are two different things. The discontinuity of the integrand in the range of integration is the origin of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The improper integral: $$\int_1^3f(x)dx$$ does not converge. In fact, using Quotient test for it gives us: $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}(x-1)^{\color{red}{1}}f(x)\neq 0$$ and so it diverges.

Comment: Could please explain what you have done and what is Quotient test ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a plot of the function $y=\frac{1}{x^2-6x+5}$. Does it look integrable to you on the interval $[0,3]$? (Hint: pay special attention to the behaviour of the function around $x=1$.)

Comment: Thank you it make a sense by graphing but why I could find it by integrate it what is my wrong ?