# Converging integrals

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Given this integral:
$$\int_2^∞ \frac {1}{({x-2)}^{2a+b}{(2x+5)}^b} \, dx$$

How do you find out when the integral converges (i.e. what limitations must be placed on a and b for the integral to converge)?

I understand that you analyze how the integral behaves at the integration limits. So you take the limits of the integrand as it approaches the integration limits. So:
$$\frac {1}{({x-2)}^{2a+b}{9}^b}$$ when x = 2. But from this, how do you figure out whether 2a+b should be greater than, equal to, and/or less than 1?

Similarly we get:
$$\frac {1}{{x}^{2a+b}{(2x)}^b}$$ which is equal to $$\frac {1}{{x}^{2a+2b}{2}^b}$$
But again, how does this help show you the circumstances when convergence occurs?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622180/why-the-integral-int-03-frac1x2-6x5dx-doesnt-exist/622187#622187) should help you.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^1 x^p\ dx$ converges iff $p > -1$, and $\int_1^\infty x^p\ dx$ converges iff $p < -1$.  So you want $2a+b < 1$ for convergence as $x \to 2$, and
$2a+2b>1$ for convergence as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: But neither equation is of the form (x^p), and one of the integration limits is 2, which is not 0, 1, or infinity. That's why I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Try bounding the integrand from below and above and use the fact that:

$\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x^p} \, dx $ converges for $p>1$ and

$\int_0^1\frac 1 {x^p} \, dx $ converges for $p<1$

Also changing variables might help.
spoiler:

> my guess is that $2a+b=0$ and $b>1$

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: it may be easier to make the change of variables $t=x-2$ and split the new
integral into the following two 
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2a+b}(2x+5)^{b}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}%
\frac{1}{t^{2a+b}\left( 9+2t\right) ^{b}}\,dt+\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{%
t^{2a+b}\left( 9+2t\right) ^{b}}\,dt \\
&=&I_{1}+I_{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We can use the [limit comparison test](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/2924/cal78.pdf) twice, noticing that the second
integral ($I_{2}$) behaves like
\begin{equation*}
J_{2}=\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{t^{2a+2b}}\,dt=\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{
t^{p}}\,dt,\qquad p=2a+2b,
\end{equation*}
as $t\rightarrow \infty $, and the first one ($I_{1}$) like 
\begin{equation*}
J_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t^{2a+b}}\,dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t^{q}}
\,dt,\qquad q=2a+b,
\end{equation*}
as $t\rightarrow 0^{+}$. For which values of $p=2a+2b$ and $q=2a+b$ do $J_2$ and $J_1$ converge?

Comment: Thanks! However, the limits of integration are 2 and infinity, so shouldn't the lower limit of integration for I1 be 2?

Comment: @student For $t=0, x=2$. $I_1$ is convergent if and only if $J_1$ is also convergent. For which values of $q$ is $J_1$ convergent?

Comment: @student 
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2a+b}(2x+5)^{b}}\,dx &=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{
t^{2a+b}\left( 9+2t\right) ^{b}}\,dt=I_{1} \\
\int_{3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2a+b}(2x+5)^{b}}\,dx &=&\int_{1}^{\infty }
\frac{1}{t^{2a+b}\left( 9+2t\right) ^{b}}\,dt=I_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ah, alright. My mistake. I take it then that, by the comparison test, the equations with 2^b and 9^b in the denominators would also converge for the same limitations of a and b. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
x \sim 2\quad \imp \quad 2a + b > -1\,,\qquad x \to \infty\quad\imp\quad -2a - 2b + 1 <0
$$
$$ 2a + b > -1\,,\qquad a + b > \half$$